# Homemade car CD holder

Tags: technology, car, travel, container, organization

My MP3 player just broke :/ But that's not what I'm asking about. Tomorrow I'm going back home from college. I have a good many CDs that I can listen to on the way home, but they are in a case similar to the following, but the cover for each CD is opaque (don't ask me why - poor design).

[image]

This makes it very hard for me to see which CDs are where, requiring that I slide the CD out for each one before I can see what the CD is. But, since I'm driving, this is more distracting and time consuming than I'd like.

Thinking about how I could remedy this, I thought about the CD holders made specifically for cars. But, as I doubt I'll use it past tomorrow driving home, I'd rather not spend the $10 or so to get one and spend the effort to go to the store. I don't have any transparent CD cases or anything similar lying around as CDs are quite outdated.

[image]

Is there any way I can make something similar to the above product with the things around my house? It doesn't necessarily have to be hanging, I'd just like it to hold the CDs so they don't shift around, be accessible to me while driving, and be visible so I can tell which one is which.

Comment: I have friends who have made very creative things out of duct tape. You might want to think about making something like your second picture, either out of duct tape, or clear packing tape.

Comment: @Shokhet Good idea! However, I have never really made anything out of duct tape, a helpful answer would be useful to me :P

Comment: If I knew what to do with duct tape, I might design something....but I don't :P ....you might try some youtube research to find similar designs, and then make your own. ....if you do, feel free to post said design here, so we can all see it! ;-)

Comment: Do you want full instructions? And are you opposed to a bit of sewing?

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock You don't have to go through every stitch ;) and I don't have a sewing machine, but I have a needle and some thread. Not too experienced though, it'll be ugly, haha. If it can be avoided with relative ease that may be better. I could always modify an approach you provide

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use your current cd holder, but put a strip of masking tape on each page. Use a marker to write the title of the cd on each strip of tape.

Another trick would be to put the cd's in order. Before you leave, put them in the order you want to play them, from the front to the back of the case.

Comment: So simple! I should have thought of that

Comment: @ZachSaucier Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 3):

**Here are some plans I wanted to try:**

- If you are handy with sewing, here is a design similar to your second design.

  [urban threads.com](http://www.urbanthreads.com/tutorials.aspx?t=CD%20Holder)

[image]

Its basically where you sew pockets onto a board that is covered with cloth. The board can be made of cardboard or another light weight hard object. I planned to modify this pattern to hang on the back of the seat, though.

- Also, have you tried labelling the CD'S. Taking a piece of tape and creating a tag out of it should work.
- [Mushroomvillagers.wordpress.com](http://mushroomvillagers.wordpress.com/cd-poket-tutorial/)

[image]

This plan takes a lot of sewing. It is mostly sewed together pockets, but you may be able to avoid this by taking large pockets from other pieces of clothing and adhering them together, by adding elastic bands on the back you should be able to create a design that is similar to the one above.

***Using Duct tape or cloth glue for the steps should work. Other things that will work for creating pockets:***

- [Paper.](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-CD-Sleeve-from-Paper)

---

**Additional Info**

[Other CD covering ideas.](http://tipnut.com/cd-covers/)

[odee.com](http://www.oddee.com/item_97500.aspx): Not helpful, but really cool.

Comment: I don't have strips of fabric lying around, is there something similar I could use?

Comment: @ZachSaucier I said tape, but you could try paper. I will edit, and scrap clothes work to.